# Ansible FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: "}

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm trying to run ansible-playbook to configure hosts that can I access only using jumphost.

My yaml file is:

```
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: -o ProxyCommand="ssh -vvv -W %h:%p jumphost" -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    ansible_become_user: root
    ansible_become_method: sudo
    ansible_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_SSH_USER') }}"
    ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_SSH_PASSWORD') }}"
  hosts:
    192.168.0.[2:5]:
    192.168.0.[7:10]:
    192.168.0.[12:15]:
  children:
    cluster1:
      hosts:
        192.168.0.[2:5]:
    cluster2:
      hosts:
        192.168.0.[7:10]:
    cluster3:
      hosts:
        192.168.0.[12:15]:
    logstash:
      hosts:
        192.168.0.[2:3]:     # Cluster 1
        192.168.0.[7:8]:     # Cluster 2
        192.168.0.[12:13]:   # Cluster 3
    prometheus:
      hosts:
        192.168.0.[4:5]:     # Cluster 1
        192.168.0.[9:10]:    # Cluster 2
        192.168.0.[14:15]:   # Cluster 3
```

But when I run it I receive this error:

```
$ ANSIBLE_SSH_USER='toor' ANSIBLE_SSH_PASSWORD='*****' ansible-playbook -i inventories/inventory.yml -l cluster1 playbooks/deploy-monitoring.yml -vv
ansible-playbook [core 2.11.4]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.6 (default, Apr  9 2021, 12:30:30) [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1.0.1)]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = True
No config file found; using defaults
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: deploy-monitoring.yml ****************************************************************************************
1 plays in playbooks/deploy-monitoring.yml

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************
task path: /opt/Developments/GitLab/myproject/playbooks/deploy-monitoring.yml:2
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host 192.168.0.2: Data could not be sent to remote host
"192.168.0.2". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.2' (ECDSA) to the
list of known hosts.
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.5]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.3]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.2]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.4]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.2]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.3]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.5]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.0.4]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
fatal: [192.168.0.2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: "}
fatal: [192.168.0.3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: "}
fatal: [192.168.0.4]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: "}
fatal: [192.168.0.5]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: "}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
192.168.0.2               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
192.168.0.3               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
192.168.0.4               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
192.168.0.5               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I try to connect to the remote servers using jump host with the command I can without problem (The system require before the password for the jumphost and after the password for the remote server)

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p jumphost" toor@192.168.0.2
```

**Note:**
I run this ansible-playbook from Linux VM on my Windows pc on VirtualBox with natNetwork.
On my Windows pc run a VPN to allow access to JumpHost, I can't access directly to remote servers (192.168.0.x) from my windows and Linux.
From Linux I can access to jumphost, and remote servers (passing by jump host)

This ansible-playbook works running from a Mac pc (no use Linux VM).

Thanks for your help.
Marco

Comment: Did you define the environment vars on the linux vm (ANSIBLE_SSH_USER and ANSIBLE_SSH_PASSWORD)?

Comment: Yes I did, I pass this info by command prompt. I think this is a network problem (NAT VM) not depend from Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using `sshpass`.
I modified my yaml file as below:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: -o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh -vvv -W %h:%p ispjh" -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

and defined `$SSHPASS` as env variable with password used to connect to jump host.